# how to merge form data passed by get method with current get string?

Tags: php, html, forms, get

For example I am at url like this:

```
localhost/somewhat/?action=active
```

And I have html form:

```
<form>
    <div class="navbar-form navbar-right" name="x1">
        <select class="form-control" name="limit">
            <option selected value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

On submit I recive url like

```
localhost/somewhat/?action=active
```

But I want to recieve this url in format:

```
localhost/somewhat/?action=active&limit=20;
```

I have an idea to do this with hidden inputs and foreach get element do echo of these hidden inputs. But it's a wrong way because $_GET['key'] can be array data also..
So, how to be?

Comment: tried and it doesn't helps.

Comment: why not just make the action to be a define value when it is receive ?
or put the action to be hidden element with the value of active
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="active">
and the form method to be get

Comment: what will i do if $_GET['action'] will be presented not as string? for example $_GET['action'] = array('some_key_1'=>'val_1', 'some_key_2'=>'val_2', )

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="get_key[array_inside_get_key][]" value="123"/>,
```

solution is here: https://gist.github.com/eric1234/5802030